# How to Configure Spring Context to serve as a common context across all requests in a standalone java application?

Tags: java, spring, applicationcontext

I am creating a standalone java application which will be packaged as a jar. Now  I need to load spring context every time I execute a method in some class. Is there any way to initialize the context just once and use it across all requests. I know if I use a container like tomcat then it serves this purpose but that would be a webapp and doesn't meet my needs.

```js
import org.springframework.boot.*;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.*;
import org.springframework.stereotype.*;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@Controller
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Controller {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    @ResponseBody
    String home() {
        return "Hello World!";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Controller.class, args);
    }
}
```

Now if I execute

```js
C:\ javac Controller.java
C:\ java Controller   //Will create an application context evrytime I execute this.
```

I want something like

```js
//Request 1
C:\ java Controller   //1. Creates an Application Context in memory 2. Uses this Application Context.

//Still Application Context is in memory

//Request 2
C:\ java Controller   //Uses Application Context created by Request 1.

//Still Application Context is in memory

//Request 3
C:\ java Controller   //Uses Application Context created by Request 1.

//Still Application Context is in memory

//And so on....
```

Comment: I think you need to describe your architecture and where and when you create spring contexts a bit more to get a useful answer.

Comment: @Ralph I have edited it. Tell me if you need more details.

Comment: Can you explain more about why this can't be a web app? The config I see there looks a lot like a web app, so I think we need more information about the constraints of your environment.

Comment: @Gus The app would be called by a scheduler agent resides in the System. The agent team says they can make a call to a jar only. And I don't have permissions to alter this architecture until I don't have a solid technical blocker.

Answer (score 0):

Did you take a look at Spring Boot? Usually, when you start an application, you usually have one central instance maintaining and holding your runtime, usually on the "main" thread. This would be the place where you keep an instance of the Spring Context.

The basic idea of spring contexts is, that the context manages all dependencies and you obtain injected instances. So the way of thinking is the other way around (You invoke something that is managed by the context and not you invoke something that retrieves data from the context). Both ways are ok.

HTH, Mark